# Intergrate Laravel Library in Codeigniter Project

Tags: laravel, codeigniter

I have one library in laravel :-
https://github.com/mjaschen/collmex

I want to integrate it in my Codeigniter project, Can anyone help me in it?

Answer (score 1):

since both use composer, you can simply require it.

but since you can't use service providers...you have to call them manually (i.e. you won't get access to `alias` in laravel) except that...you can do everything as in laravel project.